# Wait for php callback on object instance and return value on function

Tags: php

I have the following function that instantiates an object and runs its method. I want to return `$to_return` but the problem is that `$to_return` does not change even when the function is using 'use' keyword. Here is the function:

```
function some_function($arg){

    $to_return = false;

    $object = new Object;

    $to_return = $object->METHOD(function($callback) use ($to_return){

        $to_return = $some_var;

    });

    $to_return = $object->runMETHOD("some_arg");

    return $to_return;

}
```

So, basically:

- `$to_return` returned is always false
- I want `some_function` to return $some_var

In short: how can I make some_function return the object changed inside the object method?

Comment: Just return $this in the method

Comment: @PeterChaula sorry, how exactly? Could you be specific to this situation please? I want the function to return `$some_var`, not an instance of an object.

Comment: to update the `$to_return` property inside the closure  then you will need to pass it by reference. i.e. `function (...) use (&$to_return) {...`.

Comment: Aren't you overwriting the `$to_return` variable?

Comment: actually now some_function returns a return from $object->runMETHOD("some_arg") call. so can you please clarify what you want to achieve? also maybe sources of object? with METHOD and runMETHOD methods

Answer (score 7):

All you miss is indicating that `$to_return` should be passed by reference:

```
function($callback) use (& $to_return)
```

Also example of working example on 3v4l: https://3v4l.org/Vfp70

I'm no internals expert, but long story short primitives are "copied" when you pass them somewhere thus what you were setting in the callback is not transfered outside. Objects, on the other hand, would behave like you expected because pointer to object is passed and original instance is modifed. Using even plain `stdClass` as such transporter would work, as illustrated in this 3v4l: https://3v4l.org/m9jJ3

Comment: Nope, this does not work... Could the difference be that you are doing this as a function and I am doing it as an object method?

Comment: No, it should still work: https://3v4l.org/mD5YD In your code you're overwriting `$to_return` in at least 2 places so that's affecting its value in the end

Answer (score 0):

Use the given solution by @malarzm BUT then also don't assign the the function to a $to_return (it has no result anyways)

So instead of

```
$to_return = $object->METHOD(function($callback) use ($to_return)
```

use:

```
$object->METHOD(function($callback) use (&$to_return)
```

Also you are overwriting the same variable before even using it here:

```
 $to_return = $object->runMETHOD("some_arg");
```

So you probably want to assign the return value of that method to a different variable.